# Compiler version range in abigen

Tags: solidity, docker, command-line, abigen

I need to have a contract using this form of pragma:

> pragma solidity >0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

When I hard code one version it works

```
+ docker run -v /my-path/contracts:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.18 --allow-paths=/sources/solc -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Swap.sol
Compiler run successful. Artifact(s) can be found in directory "/sources/abi".
```

But when I attempt to use a range it fails, it also fails if I hard code **>0.5.1 < 0.9.0**

```
compilerversion=">0.5.1 < 0.9.0"
docker run -v /my-path/:/sources ethereum/solc:"$compilerversion" --allow-paths=/sources/solc -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Swap.sol
```

And I get this output

```
+ docker run -v /my-path/contracts:/sources 'ethereum/solc:>0.5.1 < 0.9.0' --allow-paths=/sources/solc -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Swap.sol
docker: invalid reference format.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?